# iPhone: How do i get iphone power off/switch off/turn off event/notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to get a notification when iphone power off/switch off/ turn off. 
I want make a log file in which i'll be writing a timestamp of device when power off/switch off/ turn off occurs.

Comment: I don't think you can... not without a jailbroken app, that is

Comment: iOS 5 supports coreBluetooth framework, maybe it might help. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In your application delegate should be the methods:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

you will also be notified when someone push the home button or switch the app.

//EDIT: if you generally want to log the power settings:

go to your iPhone settings and choose 'Developer Settings' (I think there have to be a developer profile installed). There you can enable 'Power Logging'
(the log file would be transferred to your XCode Organizer tool)

Comment: i think he wants to do it even when his app is off, and indeed it is not something you can do.

Comment: hi, i want to log when my app is running...
I'm ready to use private libraries as i dont want to upload it appstore...

Comment: ok then the first advice is what you looking for. use applicationDidBecomeActive: and applicationDidFinishLaunching: to indicate the start of your App and applicationDidEnterBackground: and applicationWillTerminate: to indicate the end of your App runtime ;) (if it solves your problem, would you tick it, please)

Comment: hmmm....ppl please read the topic very carefully.....it says "iphone power off/switch off/ turn off event/notification??" and not application terminate event....i'm running a thread in background so that i could capture some events, i want event/notification which i'll use in log....or even a system log file which keeps records of switch on/off timestamps....plz plz helppppppp.....

Comment: Hi @jax, any luck you find in your problem plz share i need the solution for same. Thanks